# Get select value in radio button group in xpages by SSJS

Tags: radio-button, xpages, selectedvalue

I have the following requirement in an xpages application:

I have a radio button group with two options.
I have a combobox whose values ​​will be calculated from the option chosen in the radio button group. The options will be calculated from the partial refresh of the combobox associated with the onChange event of the radio button.

My problem is that I could not get the value selected on the radio button to mount the combobox options. As I'm doing the assembly through SSJS I have to get the value selected on the radio button also in SSJS. Is there any component / method on xpages that I can get the selected value from?

I know that via RPC component or jquery coould get via CSJS the selected value, but I was only wanting to use SSJS.

Grateful

Knut,

I made an example based on your suggestion, according to the code below, but it did not work. Because?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:radioGroup id="radioGroup2">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="a"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="b"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="c"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="computedField2" execMode="partial"   execId="radioGroup2">
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:radioGroup>
<xp:text
    escape="true"
    id="computedField2"
    value="#{javascript:getComponent('radioGroup2').getValue()}">
</xp:text><xp:br></xp:br><xp:br></xp:br>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
getComponent('radioGroup1').getValue()
```

Replace "radioGroup1" with your radio button group's **id**.

Here is an example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:radioGroup
        id="radioGroup1"
        value="#{viewScope.radio}">
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="a" />
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="b" />
        <xp:eventHandler
            event="onclick"
            submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial"
            refreshId="checkBoxGroup1" execMode="partial" execId="radioGroup1">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:radioGroup>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:checkBoxGroup
        id="checkBoxGroup1"
        value="#{viewScope.check}">
        <xp:selectItems>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                if (!getComponent('radioGroup1').getValue()) {
                    return [];
                }
                if (getComponent('radioGroup1').getValue() == 'a') {
                    return ['A1', 'A2'];
                }
                return ['B1', 'B2'];
            }]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:selectItems>
    </xp:checkBoxGroup>
</xp:view>
```

Instead of `getComponent('radioGroup1').getValue()`you could use `viewScope.radio` as radio's value gets stored in view scope variable in this example.

Comment: This I tried and it did not work. In the SSJS code of the combobox the value returned is null. Should I use this value in the Onchage event of the radio button and associate it with a scope variable?

Comment: It should be in the partial refresh code of the combobox where you calculate the selectItems.

Comment: Please see the new information in the problem description.

Comment: Put your example in an empty new database. This should work. Go from there then.

Comment: In the new database it worked!

Before putting the question here I had already done so. Since it did not work, I decided to post the question here. Do you know what is the reason for not working on the database I am implementing? Would it be cache? Do I have to rebuild?

Comment: Start with project clean. Look for different properties in Xsp properties between new database and old database and look if they have an impact on this example.

Comment: Have also a look at browser console (F12) for client side issues.

Comment: I was using a dojo filtering select. It seems like the problem was him. I solved replacing it with a combobox and it worked perfectly, and I did not even need to use scope variable.

Many thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

I've done similiar by either using a getComponent("RadioButtonGroup1").getValue() in the computed values for the combobox. Or you could use this:

this.getParent().getValue()

in the onChange to populate a scoped variable that you base your combobox with.

Comment: Hi, it worked!

But how could I do it without using a scope variable? I already use many and wanted to avoid creating more because of performance issues.

Comment: Using getComponent can be much worse a performance killer than that; you may want to read this (as always) great explanation from one of our gurus: http://avatar.red-pill.mobi/tim/blog.nsf/d6plinks/TTRY-942UPQ

Comment: Also, if you use requestScope, it's life is very short. Because the component is on the page, it's accessible for every request. But regardless of whether you're storing it in requestScope or viewScope, the performance impact of saving one string will be minimal.